# Can subscriber know if publisher is latched=true?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It may be useful

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/48779/can-subscriber-know-if-publisher-is-latched=true?/) by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on ROS Answers with karma: 634 on 2012-11-21

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) on 2013-09-29**:
I'd argue that only publishers should be latched on topics which use case is indifferent of knowing they are latched. Could you think of some example?

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-12-08**:
One usecase is rosbridge node which is a subscriber of topic message but also publisher to the web clients. The problem was that one rosbridge client which came late couldn't receive the topic message if two rosbridge clients attempt to subscribe a latch topic.

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-12-08**:
um.. maybe this issue describes better

https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/issues/1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'd think comparing the time of ones own (*successfull*) subscription to the timestamp in the message could serve as a **workaround**, if the mechanical details are checked. Like that the subscriber initialization probably returns before the subscription at the rosmaster is completed.

---

Originally posted by [felix k](https://answers.ros.org/users/606/felix-k/) with karma: 1650 on 2013-09-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) on 2013-09-29**:
This assumes that a message's time stamp is (near) the current time, when it was sent, which isn't necessarily true.

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-12-08**:
One workaround we found is using rospy api. http://wiki.ros.org/rospy/Overview/Publishers%20and%20Subscribers#Connection_Information.

**Comment by [jihoonl](https://answers.ros.org/users/830/jihoonl/) on 2013-12-08**:
This question was to support rosbridge. and we got it workaround with this pull request. Thanks all

https://github.com/RobotWebTools/rosbridge_suite/pull/58